# pure-strategy Nash Equilibria - game theory

Tags: game-theory

[image]

The answer to this says that the resulting normal form is $2\times 4\times 4$

This is what I've tried so far:

For the subgame of player $2$ and $3$ where player $2$ takes dilemma (2 is row, 3 is column):
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
  & FF & FM & MF & MM \\
\hline
F & 2,2 & 2,2 & 5,1 & 5,1 \\
M & 1,5 & 4,4 & 1,5 & 4,4 
\end{array}

For the subgame of player $2$ and $3$ where player $2$ takes sexes (2 is row, 3 is column):

\begin{array}{c|lcr}
  & MM & MB & BM & BB \\
\hline
M & 3,2 & 3,2 & 1,1 & 1,1 \\
B & 0,0 & 2,3 & 0,0 & 2,3 
\end{array}

For the subgame between $1$ and $2$, here is the normal form, which I'm not quite sure how to construct:

\begin{array}{c|lcr}
  & DF & DM & SM & SB \\
\hline
D & 2,3 & 3,1 & - & - \\
S & - & - & 0,3 & 3,2 
\end{array}

I'm not quite sure what goes into the blanks. Also not quite sure what would be the last $2\times 4$ normal form game. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the dotted line between the results from 2’s actions: this disqualifies FM, MF, BM, MB as valid actions because you can’t plausibly follow through. Now you can see the valid actions are:

- D, S for p1
- FD, MD, BS, MS for p2
- same as p2 for p3

You should be able to construct the 2x4x4 matrix by following the results of these actions.

Comment: How is BD possible, since Ballet is only for Sexes? Also, what does the dotted line exactly mean?

Comment: Sorry I mixed up the possible actions for D and S

Comment: Wouldn't they be DF,DM,SB,SM? Since first comes first player with D and S and then Player 2 acts. Also, what is the dotted line?

Comment: Yeah, that’s a matter of notation. The dotted line implies the players don’t fully know where they are located, the information set of p3 is either {DF, DM} or {SB, SM}.

Comment: do you maybe know where I can find  practice/explanantion of such exercises

Comment: Osborne's Introduction to Game Theory is a good book for undergrad level.